# Open a file from command line and know when the user closes it

Tags: node.js, cmd

I have a program that creates a temporary file and uses cmd to open it (with the user's default pdf viewer). I want to delete the file after they're done with it.

How would I know when the user closes the file/closes the program that opened it?

I've tried putting an `&& <do thing>` at the end of the command, but it seems to run immediately.

If it matters, it's actually a node project running child_process.exec()

Comment: `start /wait "" "file.pdf" && echo delete` works for me. (may depend on the default pdf viewer)

Comment: @Stephan Thanks a lot! The `/wait` does exactly what I needed. I'm afraid this was an easy question, but I didn't know what to look up for this.

Comment: That's just experience...